# unable to open Excel file from C# application on other device

Tags: c#, database, excel

We have a C# project that has an Excel file (Test.xls) included in the Resources folder. The Excel file properties (Build Action = Content & Copy to Output Directory = Copy always)

and the code to open it is:

```
string path = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(@"Resources\Test.xls");
MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(@"provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='" + path + "';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;");
```

When we publish this project the Excel file is published as (Test.xls.deploy) and when the new .exe file is installed on other device it gives error :

any idea how to fix this
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to install *Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Jet* on the target computer:

TechNet:

> The Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Jet provides an OLE DB interface to Microsoft Access databases, and allows SQL Server 2005 and later distributed queries to query Access databases and Excel spreadsheets.

[Download from Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734)

Comment: i did  install and setup Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Jet on the target computer but the error still exist. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is your target OS 64 bit?  If so change your app from **Any CPU** to **x86**

Comment: the platform was x86 and i changed it to any CPU. It produces a new error : "The 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local"

Comment: I've Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 setup on the device where the program was written